# Concatenation Not Working

Tags: excel, string-concatenation, vba

My delay codes are always 3 digits.  Two letters a dash (-) and a number.  I am trying to use a single line of code to detect either MT or DA, the actual classification number is irrelevant, so I want the message box to fire on the two letters only.

The code looks right, but it doesn't fire as it should.  If I take out the wild card it works.  I think I have a problem with the concatenation, but I'm not sure.  I tried putting () brackets around it but that was not help.

Additionally I tried using an or statement to capture the MT code on the other side but got nothing but an error code for type mismatch.  Any ideas?

```
If Range("L24").Value = "DA" & "*" Then
            MsgBox "The flight had a Maintenance delay"
Else

End If
```

Comment: To use wildcards use `Like` rather than `=`

Comment: The "=" operator in your post tests **equality**, i.e. if the cell value (e.g. "DAxyz") is completely equal to the concatenated value of "DA*" including an asterisk character.
The `Like` operator in the condition `If Range("L24").Value Like "DA" & "*" Then` - as @chrisneilsen mentioned - allows to use the asterisk actually as a wild card "*" in your "DA*" pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to this kind of problem would be to ignore the wildcard altogether and check the first two digits:

```
If Left(Range("L24").Value, 2) = "DA" Then
```

Comment: DataWriter, this was the perfect solution, many thanks.  There are two delay code types, DA and MT.  I tried to use the Or function but it doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I got the Or Statement to work, I wasn't putting in enough code.